ChromeDriver и Google Chrome разных версий
Сталкиваюсь с постоянной проблемой, версии ChromeDriver (для примера 114.0.5735.90 версии, по ссылке) и Google Chrome (для примера 114.0.5735.91 версии) немного отличаются друг от друга.
По этому постоянно выдает ошибку:

Иногда помогает переустановка Google Chrome и далее "калечу" файл "GoogleUpdate", этот файл при установки Google Chrome попадает в "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update", для того что бы браузер не обновлялся. На какое то время помогает, а потом опять выдает такую ошибку. Разница в одну цифру постоянно.
Как с этим бороться, что нужно делать, подскажите пожалуйста.

В качестве дополнения, нашел библиотеку pip install chromedriver-py. может поможет кому. загружает и устанавливает последнюю двоичную версию chromedriver для автоматического тестирования веб-приложений.

Вы можете воспользоваться webdriver-manager для обновления драйвера до актуальной версии.

Либо отключите автообновление браузера

Нет, увы... Проблема осталась, как то странно... иногда работает, а потом бац и ругается на драйвер (типа не соответствие версии). но потом (через какое то время) вновь заработает, может быть так блокируют... но Спасибо за ответ.
